# Git error in Powershell Direct NativeCommandError

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops

I am using PowerShell Direct to run commands via PowerShell inside a Hyper-V VM.  I am using Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V and Windows Server 2022 inside the VM as well.

I am simply trying to run `git clone ...` over PowerShell Direct.  I am an Administrator user and can perform other commands.  When I run this, I get the following error: "NativeCommandError" and "RemoteException".  The Git repo is a password-protected HTTPS repo on Azure DevOps.

I think perahps the problem is that it is trying to pop up a GUI login dialog box.  I just want it to ask for the username and password via the CLI not via the GUI.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get git to work in PowerShell Direct?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks - when I add 2>&1 to the end of the command it does the same thing pretty much.  Thoughts?

Comment: I missed that your question already contains the error message, so my tip indeed won't help (that's why I deleted my comment once I realized that). I'm afraid I can't help with avoiding the error to begin with, except to provide a link to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops) as a potential starting point.

Comment: Are "NativeCommandError" and "RemoteException" the only error message you get ? or do you have longer error messages, e.g "NativeCommandError : can't upgrade the hexadron collider" or "RemoteExcepton : the dezombulator got disuntangled" ?